# Dataloss and Recovery Techniques in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Suppose we are using five boxes for elasticsearch.Every box containing 10-12 hard disks for storing data.If in a single box, one disk is going dead , how to recover data from that box.Is there any technique available in elasticsearch for this problem.Please suggest me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Elasticsearch is a **distributed** search engine and that's exactly the point of distributing the dataset. see [the related section of definitive guide](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_distributed_nature.html) which introduce this. Search for information about the replicas too.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick reply.But if one box containing 1000gb data and in that box if that problem occurs , we will loss all 1000gb data.Its creating a major problem in our environment.Please suggest me if any other way available for this problem.